# Draw a focus frame around a custom widget

Tags: gtk, gtk3

`GtkEntry` has a nice rounded-corners frame around when it's focused. How do I get GTK to draw such a frame around my own widget (built on top of `GtkDrawArea`) when it is focused?

I skimmed through all descendants of `GtkContainer` but nothing does this. There is `GtkFrame` but it has another purpose and looks differently.

Comment: Please show some [mre] in your question

Comment: I am downvoting any question on StackOverflow without a few lines of code. Your question has no source code at all (and should have at least a few lines of  C code). Maybe you should ask it elsewhere. I am not even able to understand your question.

Comment: I believe that the "nice rounded-corners" are related to some CSS or UI file, and could be changed without changing a single line of C code. If that is the case, your question is **off-topic** on StackOverflow

Comment: Do you mean the "has-frame" property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `draw` signal of your GtkDrawingArea, use [`gtk_render_focus()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-render-focus) to draw the focus frame at the appropriate place.

Comment: it works, but frame looks different from the one of GtkEntry

Answer (score -2):

Read first the [documentation of GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/). Download [its source code](https://download.gnome.org/sources/gtk+/3.24/), and study it for inspiration.

The [`GtkWidget` abstract superclass](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html) has some [“focus-in-event” GTK signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-in-event) and some [“focus-out-event” signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-out-event) and some [“draw” GTK signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw); you could explicitly handle them.

Your drawing routines would use the [GDK](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/) library. You could have your own widget a subclass of `GtkWidget` or of `GtkBin`

#### Notice that GTK is open source,

so you can **study** (for inspiration) **the source code of [`gtk/gtkentry.c`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gtk/gtkentry.c)**.

Your GTK signal handlers would likely use [`g_idle_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) to postpone the drawing when nothing needs to run in the GTK [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (and perhaps `-O`). You many need to use the [GDB debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: With all respect to your experience, it is clear that you did not understand the question. It is not about handling signals it is merely about the looks, the drawing of a frame. My widgets already handle focus well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27996162)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I recommend to delete the question - without source code, **the question is off-topic on StackOverflow**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The absence of code in itself does not make a question off topic, and if you consider this question off-topic, why did you post an answer (with what is basically a comment in my opinion, not an answer)?